# trying to print date and time with words in python

Tags: python, datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
print(now + 'great job!)
```

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'
```

Why am I getting this and how do I print the time with the words so it shows up like this

```
2018-04-05 20:56:06.017390 great job!
```

Thanks!

Comment: So the error tells you that you can't use `+` for time and string

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'` Error message is veeery clear. You can't 'add' string to the `datetime.datetime` object. You need to convert it to string first to be able to concatenate it:

```
print(str(now) + 'great job!')
```

You can use [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) on Python 3.6+

```
print(f'{now} great job')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need string conversion and try this

```
>>> print(str(now) + ' greate job')
```